# How to dynamically alter the CSS of a pseudo element with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a pseudo element I want to alter the `top:` of:

```
.content:after {
  top: 30px; //this will change
}
```

The amount of change is variable and retrieved with JQuery:

```
var $position = $(this).offset().top;
```

I know you cannot use `.css()` to alter a pseudo elements CSS and that the preferred method is to toggle an existing class. But that wont work with as rules in my class would be dynamic.

I am a little stuck as to how to go about this. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004507/how-to-apply-jquery-to-elementbeforehover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:after` is equivalent to adding a child element to the end of the selected element. So if it's possible, you could move the styling to a new child element which you will be able to alter with JQuery. So your html would look like:

```
<div class="content">
    ... other content ...
    <div class="content-after"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.content > .content-after {
  top: 30px; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is the only way. I avoided it because I `.content:after` allowed me to extend `filter: drop-shadow` over the pseudo element nicely